# Can't get dynamically generated tile working (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I have the method, which is executed in Application_Deacitvated/Closing().

```
public bool createBackTile()
    {
        if(AlarmClock.IsExists())
        {

            ImageBrush background = new ImageBrush()
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/BackBackgroundTheme.png", UriKind.Relative)),
                AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Center,
                AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center
            };

            // Preparing tile image.
            TextBox tileImageData = new TextBox()
            {
                Text = AlarmClock.Read().ToShortTimeString(),
                FontSize = 45,
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                //Background = background,
                Height = 173,
                Width = 173,
                HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                Padding = new Thickness(-12),
                Margin = new Thickness(0),
                Clip = new RectangleGeometry { Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 173, 173) }
            };

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas()
            {
                Width = 173,
                Height = 173,
                Background = background,
                Margin = new Thickness(0)
            };

            canvas.Children.Add(tileImageData);

            // Saving tile image.
            WriteableBitmap tileImage = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
            tileImage.Render(canvas, null);
            tileImage.Render(tileImageData, null);
            tileImage.Invalidate();
            using(var stream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().CreateFile("/Shared/ShellContent/BackBackground.jpg"))
            {
                tileImage.SaveJpeg(stream, 173, 173, 0, 100);
            }

            // Sets data for tile.
            StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData()
            {
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("BackgroundAlarmSet.png", UriKind.Relative),
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/BackBackground.jpg"),
                BackContent = "",
                BackTitle = "",
            };

            // Sets tile.
            ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault().Update(tileData);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

So, as you can see, I want to generate tile with my text in the center of it with image background "BackBackgroundTheme.png". That tile I'm trying to save in IsolatedStorage and assign it to BackBackgroundImage.

But it doesn't work. The tile is flipping over but the BackBackground is completly black. I have loaded this manipulated background and it seems that's indeed just black box. So, how to get it working?

Comment: Have you stepped through it making sure its hitting all your code?  At first glance everything appears correct.

Comment: Yes, I've setted breakpoint for every single line and it seems that all line are executed correctly.

Comment: Small change, I've added "using" after "tileImage.Invalidate();" and now the tile is flipping over, but the BackBackground is completly black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found out where the problem is.

It seems, that generation of tile image isn't done properly in Application_Closing/Deactivating(). So I moved image generation to somwhere else and now, when application is closing/deactivating, I just set previously generated image to a tile.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/BackBackground.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)`

Comment: I dont have my code that I wrote that does this available to me right now, but I do have the URL of the code I used to get me rolling.  https://github.com/Windcape/Diverse/blob/master/LocalLiveTileExample/LocalLiveTileExample/TileGenerator.cs

Comment: Well, I have loaded this image from isostore in application and it seems, that indeed it is just black box! :O So it seems that's the problem with creating this image, not with assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
canvas.Children.Add(tileImageData);
canvas.UpdateLayout();
        // Saving tile image.
        WriteableBitmap tileImage = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
```